# Is it secure? Owncloud in DMZ and refer to internal fileserver

Tags: dmz, owncloud

Is this a secure setup?

Having an (linux based) Owncloud Server, with Let's-Encrypt SSL Certificate. This server provides shares to the clients, which are SMB connections to an internal File Server

The connection is as follows:

- DNS Entry --> points to private, public IPv4 Address.
- This address has an open port in the firewall, forwarding to the IP in DMZ. HTTPs and WWW are allowed
- The SMB connection directs to an internal File server, which is in the internal network segment. only port 445 TCP is allowed
- connections are HTTPs

*Necessary maintenance:*

- update owncloud
- update the linux server and file server
- maintain the firewall

of course as well:

- monitoring and backup
- awarenes of users and admins (maybe most critical point)

Comment: Your maintenance plan is missing backups and monitoring. - And  note that security depends as much, if not more on configuration, the behaviour of your admins & users than it does on infrastructure design.  A valid TLS certificate *for example* does not mitigate keeping the default admin password unchanged.

Comment: You are right, of course! We are doing that, but I missed listing it...
but the infrastructure design as such is safe?